# Inner Join Two SOQL Objects Without Relationship

Tags: salesforce, soql

I'm not familiar with SOQL or Salesforce configuration but I've been asked to come up with a tool to easily import files as attachments to objects.

I'm using the Developer Console in Salesforce to figure this out. I found that the attached files are a custom object type named "File_Manager_File__c". This object contains several fields such as "File_Name__c", "Id" and most pertinently "Parent_ID__c". However "Parent_ID__c" is Apex Type: string so as far as I can tell it's not an actual child relationship (as my limited Salesforce understanding goes). Another field, "Parent_Object_name__c" is Apex Type: string and returns other objects that I would expect to have files attached (eg. "Job", "Contract", "Opportunity")

Since there doesn't seem to be an actual relationship is there still a way to join in SOQL this Object and objects that can have files attached to them such as "Order" (which has "ID" as a field)?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like someone has done a clumsy reimplementation of the out-of-the-box Content-based attachments feature in Salesforce. The use of text fields is because Salesforce does not allow custom polymorphic relationships, like `LinkedEntityId` on the native `ContentDocumentLink` junction object.

There's no way to perform a join in SOQL without a defined relationship in the schema. These records presumably could be imported using a tool like Data Loader by populating `Parent_ID__c` and `Parent_Object_name__c` directly with values like `001000000000001` and `Account`, but you won't be able to query those records without performing the join synthetically in Apex or whatever language an external client is written in.

Answer (score -1):

you can import theses data in database for example Postgresql.Only create the tables in the postgresql and import the data. So you can make any query.